# How to Run c# application through Command Prompt?

Tags: c#

I have Two classes.
Test.cs, Entity.cs.

I have put this two files in one folder "CommandTest".

*Test.cs Class

```
namespace Demo
{
 public class Test
{
 public static Entity entity= new Entity();
 public static void Main(string[] args)
{
Console.WriteLine("Demo");
}
```

*Entity.cs class

```
namespace Demo
{
public class Entity
{
Console.WriteLine("entity");
}
}
```

When I am Trying to run it through "Visual Studio Command Prompt".
It shows Error,

> *Test.cs(10,28): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Entity'
>           does not exist in the namespace 'Demo' (are you missing an assembly
>           reference?)*

I am not getting why it is shows error. Because both class have same namespace.
How can I run it through Command Prompt.

Thanks.

Comment: What command are you running on the command line? And I assume you are trying to compile it, not run it? Likely you just didn't tell the compiler about `Entity.cs`. It needs to be explicitly told about all necessary files, it won't just search a directory (as far as I am aware).

Comment: **Console.WriteLine("entity");** needs to be inside a method.

Comment: Can I ask why you aren't writing a unit test class instead? (judging by your filename, that is what you are looking to do)

Comment: Sorry, I am trying to compile it. csc Test.cs for Compile. Then it shows error.

Comment: You said that, It needs to be explicitly told about all necessary files. Can you tell me how can i apply it explicitly ?

Comment: @user3582190: You now have answers that explain how to add the other file. Any reason you aren't just using visual studio to do your compiling for you? If it is because you are only compiling some classes in your project for testing then you might want to look into how to do proper "unit testing" in your project.

Comment: I have created reusable component. I also want to use this component to other people. Then its easy to use them. that's why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use all files when calling `csc`. It doesn't try to find the code files itself. Try this:

```
csc /out:Test.exe Test.cs Entity.cs
```

Or, maybe easier:

```
csc /out:Test.exe *.cs
```

Also, read the related [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78f4aasd.aspx).

Don't forget to add this code block in a method too:

```
namespace Demo
{
    public class Entity
    {
        public void SomeMethod() /* here */
        {
            Console.WriteLine("entity");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks its worked. It is for compile. Can you tell me how to run. I also want to pass string as argument to Main method.

Comment: Just run `Test.exe argument1 argument2`.

Comment: class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Entity entity = new Entity();
            System.Runtime.Remoting.ObjectHandle objectHandler = Activator.CreateInstance(null, "ConsoleApplication1.Employee");
            object obj = objectHandler.Unwrap();
            Console.WriteLine(obj);
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"D:\Reshma\Command\Demo\Text.cs", obj.ToString());
        }

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I want to run two files through command prompt with pass argument as a class name to Main method. With this third class file is also available in same folder.

Comment: It is totally unclear to me what you want to achieve. Try create a new question and put in as much information on what you are doing and want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

you need to provide name of all classes explicitly. so in your case you will execute

```
csc.exe /out:ExecutableName.exe Entity.cs Test.cs
```